# how to access keys in an object which have a hyphen in them?

Tags: typescript

I have this object:

```
{
    "type": "fill",
    "id": "asdf",
    "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#440d0d"
    }
}
```

and I want to access fill-color.
I am trying to get it by:

```
if (mapStyle["paint"]){
    const fillColor = mapStyle['paint']["fill-color"]
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"fill-color"' can't be used to index type '{ "fill-antialias"?: PropertyValueSpecification<boolean> | undefined; "fill-opacity"?: DataDrivenPropertyValueSpecification<number> | undefined; ... 4 more ...; "fill-pattern"?: DataDrivenPropertyValueSpecification<...> | undefined; } | ... 7 more ... | { ...; }'.
  Property 'fill-color' does not exist on type '{ "fill-antialias"?: PropertyValueSpecification<boolean> | undefined; "fill-opacity"?: DataDrivenPropertyValueSpecification<number> | undefined; ... 4 more ...; "fill-pattern"?: DataDrivenPropertyValueSpecification<...> | undefined; } | ... 7 more ... | { ...; }'.ts(7053)
(property) "paint"?: {
    "fill-antialias"?: PropertyValueSpecification<boolean> | undefined;
    "fill-opacity"?: DataDrivenPropertyValueSpecification<number> | undefined;
    ... 4 more ...;
    "fill-pattern"?: DataDrivenPropertyValueSpecification<...> | undefined;
} | ... 8 more ... | undefined
```

What is the problem here? I don't really understand this error message.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you intend on using typescript? If so you should properly type your `mapStyle` object using an interface and then you'll be able to access your properties with dot notation e.g. `mapStyle.paint.fillColor`

Answer (score 0):

I would define a type for the `fillColor` constant. The error complains about the type implicitly set to `any`.

```
if (mapStyle["paint"]){
    const fillColor: string = mapStyle['paint']["fill-color"];
}
```

or

```
if (mapStyle["paint"]){
    const fillColor = mapStyle['paint']["fill-color"] as string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in this specific case i found the correct types:

```
import {
  CircleLayerSpecification,
  FillLayerSpecification,
  LayerSpecification,
  LineLayerSpecification,
  RasterLayerSpecification,
} from 'mapbox-gl'
```

now all the typings work...

sorry for that stupid question.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1: Define string on the constant**

```
if (mapStyle["paint"]){
    const fillColor: string = mapStyle['paint']["fill-color"];
}
```

**Solution 2: Casting**

```
if (mapStyle["paint"]){
    const fillColor = mapStyle['paint']["fill-color"] as string;
}
```

**Solution 3: Typing (my recommendation)**
Create an interface to declare the element. This is a pretty good way to avoid always using any (data).

```
export interface YourModel{
    type?: string;
    id?: string,
    paint?: YourChildModel;
}

export interface YourChildModel{
    "fill-color"?: string;
}
```

Then

```
const mapStyle:YourModel = methodToRecoverValues();

[...]

if (mapStyle.paint){
    const fillColor = mapStyle['paint']["fill-color"];
}
```